# How could an oracle that knows the true distribution of things would still incur some errors?

Tags: distributions, error, oracle

> The ideal model is an oracle that simply knows the true probability distribution that generates the data. Even such a model will still incur some error on many problems, because there may still be some noise in the distribution. In the case of supervised learning, the mapping from $x$ to $y$ may be inherently stochastic,or $y$ may be a deterministic function that involves other variables besides those included in $x$. The error incurred by an oracle making predictions from the true distribution $p(x, y)$ is called the Bayes error..
>
> [*Deep Learning*, Bengio, Goodfellow and al](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html)

I don't get why "*an oracle that simply knows the true probability distribution that generates the data*" would still incur some errors. If you know the distribution you know what the truth is, isn't it? Or can the noise create some outliers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distributions have variability.

While I might know that I am drawing from $N(0,1)$, I do not know the exact value that I will draw, and I can’t reliably make predictions with variance less than $1$, since that is the variance of the data-generating process.